# Does the order of reversing a 2D fft matter?

Tags: image, fft, ifft

I have been trying to apply the fft first on the rows and then on the columns resulting from the first application.

My question is, when I try to apply the ifft, do I need to apply it to columns first and then rows, the other way or does it not matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it should not matter.  What are you seeing?  If you reverse the order (rows and columns) and you get a different answer you probably have a bug.  Are you using a library for the FFT or a roll your own approach?  And...if you are using a library, do they have a 2D version available?

Comment: im doing my own, just wanted to confirm it did not matter, thanks